# How to solve The argument type 'Future<File> Function(Map<String, dynamic>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<File> in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to dart/flutter and been few weeks stuck with a problem

> The argument type 'Future Function(Map<String, dynamic>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr Function(Map<String, dynamic>,

How to solve it? My Code Is

```
File _file =
              await Executor().execute(fun1: _writeFileToDiskIsolated, arg1: data);
    
          _gotImage = _file;
        }
    
        return _gotImage;
      }
    
      static Future<File> _writeFileToDiskIsolated(
          Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
        File _theFile = File(data['path'] + 'imagetest');
        _theFile.writeAsBytes(data['response']);
        return _theFile;
      }
```

here is a snapshot of editor  Issue with red line

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `Future` to `FutureOr`

```dart
static FutureOr<File> _writeFileToDiskIsolated(
          Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
        File _theFile = File(data['path'] + 'imagetest');
        _theFile.writeAsBytes(data['response']);
        return _theFile;
      }
```